# Are named volumes automatically deleted once the stack is removed in Swarm?

Tags: postgresql, docker, swarm

I have a Swarm cluster with 2 workers and one manager. I use a named volume for a database. Every time I remove the stack and deploy it again (testing purposes), the whole named volume is lost. Any idea on why this might happen? It's just a Postgres database with a very simple named volume.